# How to auto-complete filenames in sub-directories when opening them for editing using e.g. `:e </path/to/file>`?

Tags: autocompletion, file

> How to autocomplete filenames in sub-directories when opening them for editing using e.g. `:e </path/to/file>`?

When opening files in sub-directories for editing using e.g. `:e </path/to/file>`, I often press `TAB` multiple times to autocomplete file and/or directory names.

My problem is that using `TAB` for auto-completion, I cannot move into the targeted subdirectory. Instead subsequent `TAB`s return filenames in the current directory cyclically.

By pressing `<space>` and deleting it again after having auto-completed the targeted sub-directory, I'm able to move into the sub-directory and autocomplete filenames in that directory.

Is there a smarter way to move into a sub-directories when `TAB`'ing for filename auto-completion?

**Targeted sub-directory**: `watchdog_io`

[image]

**Targeted file in sub-directory**: `io.py`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don’t do the `'path'` trick. [The `'path'` option affects many of vim’s best navigational techniques.](https://github.com/tpope/vim-apathy)

Instead (and I only learned about this recently—see `:help 'wildmenu'`), when you’re dealing with directories:

- use <kbd>Down</kbd> to “drill down” into the subdirectory and start completing filenames below
- use <kbd>Up</kbd> to “move up” into the parent directory and complete filenames above
- use your `'wildchar'` to cycle in the current directory (as you’ve already noted)

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by `wildchar` - do you mean `TAB`? Can you refer to a specific `:help` page?

Comment: In my case, both `<down>` and `<up>` works for drilling down the sub-directory, however, I cannot seem to move up into the parent directory.

Comment: @Shuzheng see `:help 'wildchar'` for that—it defaults to `<Tab>`. For the rest, see `'wildmenu'`

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your .vimrc:

```
set path+=**
```

This will also search in all subdirectories.

Then use the `:find` command. Start writing a part of the filename, for example...

```
:find io
```

...and then when you press Tab, it will autocomplete or offer possible matches from which you can choose. It will find io.py even if it's in a subdirectory.